# How can I use "Do while loop in laravel blade" file

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on laravel and i need to use **do While loop** in laravel blade using like **@foreach()** directive. 
I am already doing it using

```
@php
$count=0;
    do {
       $count++ 
@endphp
<span> my all html here </span>
@php
} while($count <10);
@endphp
```

Kindly tell me **Best way using DO-While** not **foreach or while**. Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with what you have shown us? Does it not work? Does it do the wrong thing?

Comment: `@for($count = 1; $count <= 10; $count++)` or `@foreach(range(1, 10) as $count)`

Comment: The best way to use a do-while for this is to not use a do-while. It's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a do-while loop at all. A for loop will do.

```
@for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    <span> my all html here </span>
@endfor
```

--- EDIT

You stated in the comments that you need to output this at least once, even if there are no entries for you to cycle through. If that is truly the case, you do not need a do-while loop at all. You can amend my above code to look like this.

```
@include('partials/my-partial')

@for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
    @include('partials/my-partial')
@endfor
```

Then `partials/my-partial.blade.php` would look like the following.

```
<span> my all html here </span>
```

If you have to display once at least, simply output the content. It's a waste to add a loop if there's a chance nothing will be present.

Comment: Why not do-while? I have to display at least one time even array is null. This only can be done using do-while, and I have asked how to use **do-while**. I don't want any other suggestion  pleas.

Comment: @WaqasAltaf do-while is not the correct way to do this. I will update my answer to include your comments.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```php
@php 
$count=0 
@endphp
@while($count <10)
    <span> my all html here </span> 
@php 
$count++ 
@endphp
@endwhile
```

ref link  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function in PHP to achieve this in your blade with just a clean interpolation only syntax.

```
@foreach(range(1,10) as $current)
  <span> my all html here </span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: what if my variable is null?

Comment: @WaqasAltaf which variable?